# Getting all repos from an github orginisation in Dart

Tags: dart

I'm looking for some API so that I can in Dart code find out the names of the public repos of a github organization.

For example, say I want to find out all the names of the repos from the dart-lang organization. I would like to get a List like:

```
  [
    'dart-lang/pub-dartlang',
    'dart-lang/dart-samples',
    'dart-lang/api.dartlang.org',
    'dart-lang/www.dartlang.org',
    ...
  ];
```

I'm interested in both a server and client side solution.

Comment: I wasn't one of the downvotes, but this is a terrible question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Antiga what is terrible about it? Is it better like this? any suggestions? I was mainly documenting something I found out....

Comment: @Kasper. Not to criticize you, but I believe this is considered a bad question because a simple search would have turned up an answer. pub.dartlang.org has a search feature. A simple search for 'github' produces a hit: https://pub.dartlang.org/search?q=github'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [github](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/github/2.3.1/github.browser/RepositoriesService/listOrganizationRepositories.html) pub package.

For the browser:

```dart
import 'package:github/browser.dart';

main() async {
  final service = createGitHubClient().repositories;

  await for (final repo in service.listOrganizationRepositories('dart-lang')) {
    print(repo.fullName);
  }
}
```

For the server:

```dart
import 'package:github/server.dart';

main() async {
  final service = createGitHubClient().repositories;

  await for (final repo in service.listOrganizationRepositories('dart-lang')) {
    print(repo.fullName);
  }
}
```